# Best filesystem choices for NFS storing VMware disk images

Tags: linux, nfs, zfs, opensolaris

Currently we use an iSCSI SAN as storage for several VMware ESXi servers. I am investigating the use of an NFS target on a Linux server for additional virtual machines. I am also open to the idea of using an alternative operating system (like OpenSolaris) if it will provide significant advantages.

What Linux-based filesystem favours very large contiguous files (like VMware's disk images)? Alternatively, how have people found ZFS on OpenSolaris for this kind of workload?

Answer (score 1):

ZFS is perfect for this kind of setup primarily because of deduplication, assuming your ZFS host is somewhat decent in the RAM and CPU categories.  If all you need is a filer based setup and your hardware is OpenSolaris compatible, I would strongly suggest you take a look at [NexentaStor](http://www.nexenta.com).

Comment: Is NexentaStor really "enterprise" ready?

Comment: It is based on OpenSolaris, so if you were already considering that route, NexentaStor basically takes Opensolaris and wraps it into a nice, filer type package with a web interface.  All the great things about Opensolaris that you would have wanted to use if you rolled your own are already there, and then some.  It has a VMDC plugin that's optimized for ESX:  http://www.nexenta.com/corp/applications/vmdc.  Yes, I'd say it's enterprise ready.  It's perfect for what you want to do.